# Question on Moment of inertia about center of mass of a smooth plane curve.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, plane-curves

This question is in continuation to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/618993/2987) and motivated to answer this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414). If I have an answer to it, then I can prove a special case of this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/165038/14414).

Consider two smooth plane curves $C \equiv (X_C(s),Y_C(s))$ and $S \equiv (X_S(s),Y_S(s))$ represented in arc length parametrization. Curve $C$ is asymptotic to a straight line $(a,s)$ in arc length parametrization, where $a$ is a constant. As $s\to\infty$ the curve $S$ approaches (converges) to a point in the plane, as $s\to\infty$.

Now we define moment of intertia about its center of mass, of a segment of curve $C$ between $s=s_1$ and $s = s_2$ as $$I_C(s_1,s_2) = \int_{s1}^{s_2} ((X_C(s)-X_{C_{cm}})^2 + (Y_C(s)-Y_{C_{cm}})^2)  ds$$ where $(X_{C_{cm}},Y_{C_{cm}})$ is the center of mass of the segment under consideration given by $X_{C_{cm}} = \frac{1}{s_2-s_1}\int_{s_1}^{s_2}X_C(s)ds$ and $Y_{C_{cm}} = \frac{1}{s_2-s_1}\int_{s_1}^{s_2}Y_C(s)ds$. Similarly $$I_S(s_1,s_2) = \int_{s1}^{s_2} ((X_S(s)-X_{S_{cm}})^2 + (Y_S(s)-Y_{S_{cm}})^2)  ds$$ where $X_{S_{cm}} = \frac{1}{s_2-s_1}\int_{s_1}^{s_2}X_S(s)ds$ and $Y_{S_{cm}} = \frac{1}{s_2-s_1}\int_{s_1}^{s_2}Y_S(s)ds$.

I'd like to prove/disprove the following statement.

Statement : Given any $s = s_1$ we can always find a sufficiently large $L$ such that for all $s_2 > L$, we have $I_C(s_1,s_2) > I_S(s_1,s_2)$.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/175862/14414

Comment: In case it has already occurred to you to do so: It might be helpful to first simplify the problem through the parallel axis theorem, which states that the moment of inertia $I^{(\text{p})}$ about a point $\text{p}$ is equal to the moment of inertia $I^{(\text{cm})}$ about the center of mass $\text{cm}$ (specially, a *parallel* axis through the center of mass) plus the squared perpendicular distance between the points $\text{p}$ and $\text{cm}$: $I^{(\text{p})}=I^{(\text{cm})}+\|\text{p}-\text{cm}\|^2$. This means it suffices to solve the special case in which the C.o.M. is at the origin.

Comment: ^In case it *hasn't* occurred to you, I meant to say. Oops

Comment: @DavidH : I know. The CoM can safely assumed to be origin without any loss to the problem. Infact thats what RobJohn did in his answer : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/618993/2987

Comment: @DavidH : In case you were wondering, Altogether elimination of CoM is not possible$(X_{cm},Y_{cm})$ is the center of mass of the segment of curve we are considering, and not a fixed constant for all segments of the curve. It changes when we change when we move from one segment of the curve to another segment of the curve. Ofcourse it also changes when we move to another curve.

Comment: Ah, so it does. That makes things a little more interesting.

Comment: The units make no sense to me. I think the integral needs to be over an area in order to produce ${\rm length}^4$ units.

Comment: @ja72 :  dont change question for sake of units. This inst physics, just math definitions. In any case for physical meaning, the curve is  of uniform linear mass density equal to 1.

Comment: Yes mass you call it moment of inertia which is generally $\int \rho ( x^2 +y^2)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$. Then don't call it like this if it is not.

Comment: @ja72 : I dont understand why you are goint to two dimensions, the curve is just a uniform string. There is no question of area here.

Comment: Ok, I get it ${\rm d}I = \mu (x^2+y^2) {\rm d} s$ with $\mu=1$.

Comment: To prove mathematically one needs the shape functions for _C_ and _S_. Otherwise you are left with common sense, which dictates that when $s\rightarrow \infty$ the center of mass and moment of inertia remain finite for _S_ and become infinite for _C_.

Comment: @ja72 : Both curves are of infinite length. Thats what i mean by asymptotic and approaching as $s\to\infty$

Comment: $s\to\infty$ means both are of infinite length.

Comment: @ja72 : I have added a detail that how curve $C$ is asymptotic to a straight line $(a,s)$ in arc length parametrization, where $a$ is a fixed constant.

Comment: The first curve $S$ remains within a bounded region while $C$ diverges off to infinity so asymptotically we have $(X_{\rm Com},Y_{\rm Com})\sim(a,s_2)$ and $(X_{\rm Som},Y_{\rm Som})\sim({\rm const},{\rm const})$. This gives $I_C\sim\mathcal{O}(s_2^3)$ and $I_S\sim\mathcal{O}(s_2)$ and it follows that $I_C$ will eventually dominate over $I_S$. The only challenge I can see (read: tedious work) is to make the argument precice enough (depending on the level or rigour you want). This seems so obvious and simple so what am I missing here?

Comment: @Winther : Agree it seems obvious, but I do need the "make the argument precice enough" with mathematically complete proof. I am not only interested in the result but also the way we prove it here, as I want to do more with... If its so obvious I still not able to prove it and that puzzles me!

Comment: @Winther : I agree with you. Can you write a few more lines to make the argument a bit more precise, I believe it and understand it but need a few more math steps to make it less hand waving. This is my request. you can possibly add it as an answer, for me to accept it.